# Find min element's index of a large list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i know some way to find the min or max element's index, but when i deal with a large list. ghc said:"stack overflow"

So i go to stack overflow.

```
Prelude> :m Data.List
Prelude Data.List> let a = reverse [1..10000000]
Prelude Data.List> elemIndex  (minimum a) a
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

This way is better than using elemIndex but it can't solve 'reverse [1..100000000]'.

```
subset [] = [[]]
subset (x:xs) = s ++ map ( x : ) s
where s = subset xs

minIndex xs = snd . minimum $ zip xs [0..]
```

How can i find min element's index of a large list?

You'd better not use other module, just using prelude.

Comment: The problem is not with `elemIndex`, but with `minimum`, or rather, `minimum . reverse`.

Comment: You can write `[10000000,9999999..1]`. `reverse` is the problem here, because it keeps the whole list in memory. Is there a reason why you want to use `reverse`?

Comment: @sapanoia granted, though principle it shouldn't be a problem to keep a list with 100 M entries in memory. Indeed this only causes a stack overflow in GHCi; in a compiled program (even without optimisations) it “merely” bogs down the system with 19 GB of memory consumption...

Comment: @leftaroundabout May I borrow some RAM from your machine? On a more serious note: I interpreted "10000000" as "*some arbitrarily large number, could be bigger*". And even if your machine has 10GB of free RAM to spare, you may still take a performance hit, for example by clobbering the memory bus.

Answer (score 1):

```
elemIndex (foldl1' min a) a
```

The essential part is using `foldl1' min` instead of `minimum`.  The evaluation of `minimum` builds and returns a huge redex, whose evaluation causes stack overflow.

All the gory details: https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27

A general discussion of strictness in relation to performance in Haskell: https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Strictness